# How do I fix my melted stove top?

Tags: metal, stove, fire-hazard, stove-top

I was boiling water and turned the setting to highest, left it for less than five minutes and the next thing that happened our electricity fluctuated and our burner was on (a small) fire. I had to turn the setting twice to turn it off. A small section of our burner melted and so did a small part of the pot I used. We covered the burner and the knob that was used for it as well.

My questions are:

- Is the stove, excluding that one melted burner,still safe to use?
- If it's fixable, how do I fix it?

P.S
Our stove is old, not sure when it was bought.

Comment: Was the burner dirty when you turned it on?  Can you show a picture of exactly where the fire started?

Answer (score 3):

Many times the element(s) crack and burn up like what happened to you. There are replacement elements for most stoves you need to match the size. To replace unplug the stove and usually there are screws or slip on spade connectors (these spade connectors are special high temp ones) if one needs replaced don't use normal ones from the big box stores, unless they are stamped high temp (I think 900 deg F) The stove should be fine to use just not that burner until replaced.
[A link to 1](http://www.walmart.com/ip/EXACT-REPLACEMENTS-ERS46Y15-Range-Surface-Elements-6in-PK-4-Turn/24538848?action=product_interest&action_type=title&item_id=24538848&placement_id=irs-106-t1&strategy=PWVAV&visitor_id&category=&client_guid=b45e228a-4490-413f-8c02-6ac43d3542cd&customer_id_enc&config_id=106&parent_item_id=40214708&parent_anchor_item_id=40214708&guid=c74b3865-885d-4ce9-8581-e64d93489176&bucket_id=irsbucketdefault&beacon_version=1.0.1&findingMethod=p13n) element not very expensive.